# Interface with a list as property

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, interface

I want to implement an interface that's quite simple :

```
public interface IProfession
{
    List<string> jobSkills { get; set; }
    void setSkills();
}


public class artisan : IProfession
{
    int money = 1200;

    public List<string> jobSkills;

    public void setSkills(){
        jobSkills.Add("baratin");
        jobSkills.Add("marchandage");
        jobSkills.Add("monde_naturel");
        jobSkills.Add("royaume_natal");
        jobSkills.Add("sagacite");
        jobSkills.Add("statut");
        jobSkills.Add("statut");
    }
}
```

Vstudio tells me that Models.artisan does not implement interface member Models.IProfession.jobSkills.

Why? I have tried this too :

```
public class artisan : IProfession
{
    int money = 1200;

    protected List<string> jobSkills;

    public List<string> _jobSkills
{ 
    get { return jobSkills;}
    set { jobSkills = value; }
} 

    public void setSkills(){
        jobSkills.Add("baratin");
        jobSkills.Add("marchandage");
        jobSkills.Add("monde_naturel");
        jobSkills.Add("royaume_natal");
        jobSkills.Add("sagacite");
        jobSkills.Add("statut");
        jobSkills.Add("statut");
    }
}
```

but it does not work either (same error). can someone explain what I'm missing?
Thank you

Comment: Very tempted to close this as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface requires a **property** jobSkills. You will need to implement a **property** then:

```
public interface IProfession
{
    List<string> JobSkills { get; set; }
    void SetSkills();
}    

public class Artisan : IProfession
{
    public List<string> JobSkills { get; set; };

    public void SetSkills()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Gratz. Got to re-read the basics.

Thank you, I'll validate this in a few minutes.

Would you mind telling me how the line I wrote is named if it's not a property though?

Comment: @DoctorPrisme Read the link I posted above, that will explain the difference.

Comment: @DavidG : well, it was indeed the same source of problem but I had no idea of it, as the message of VS wasn't empathetic on that point; and linking to that question wouldn't have helped me. However your link is useful. Thank you.

Comment: @DoctorPrisme That's the only reason I didn't hammer it closed, Though there may be a better question/answer that is a real dupe

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
public List<string> jobSkills { get; set; }
```

Also in your method you need to initialize the list.

```
public void setSkills()
{
    if(jobSkills == null)
       jobSkills = new List<string>();

    jobSkills.Add("baratin");
    jobSkills.Add("marchandage");
    jobSkills.Add("monde_naturel");
    jobSkills.Add("royaume_natal");
    jobSkills.Add("sagacite");
    jobSkills.Add("statut");
    jobSkills.Add("statut");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)